# Opera and Chrome Adding Height to TD Elements

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-table, opera

I'm having some trouble figuring out why both Opera and Chrome add height to the `<td>` elements, as seen on the following page: http://sentry.eleora.com/home. If you open the page in Firefox (which I assume to be the most standards-based browser—maybe I'm wrong), you'll see the `<td>` elements at the intended height. Open the page in Opera and Chrome, however, and you'll find added height. Anyone know why this is happening? (I apologize in advance if it's a simple fix; I've tried editing a variety of CSS properties and can't seem to figure it out.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `li` element has more height than the clickable a element.

`.ed-landing-page #primary-nav .menu-item a` has `height:93px`, where

`.ed-landing-page #primary-nav .menu-item` has `height:98px`

That's causing the div mismatch in Opera, and I'm not sure why firefox is handling it gracefully,

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. That difference shouldn't be affecting things in the way that concerns me. On the page cited above, check out the `<td>` element that contains the banner logo. Check it out in both Firefox and Opera, and you'll see a height difference. That's my issue: where is that height difference coming from? (Worth mentioning that I started testing in IE last night, and the height issue is a problem there, too.)